# When a whole pane changes in JavaFX, should I have various FXML files?

Tags: java, javafx

In various parts of my JavaFX application I have lists with entries that the user will create, but to avoid having a horrible empty experience, I want to display something entirely different until the user created the first entry.

For example, when you go to the websites tab, first you see this:

[image]

and after you add the first site, it will replaced with something like this (still missing the site as I'm building the app):

[image]

How should this be modeled? Two separate FXML that end up being two different scenes that I switch?

Regarding using a stack pane, it doesn't really work because controls are see-through and stack panes are designed to apply effects:

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. How are you displaying these "entries": if via a virtualized control (table view or list view, etc), they have `placeholder` properties that can be used specifically for that purpose. Otherwise, maybe consider creating a custom component that mimics that.

Comment: @James_D: it is a more complex set of controls than just a list. There's some chrome around the lists that will be hidden as well when displaying the empty experience.

Comment: @James_D: there, I added a couple of screenshots. Does that help?

Comment: I would probably define a custom component that exposed an `ObservableList<XXX>` where `XXX` is an appropriate type representing the web sites in the list. Make it encapsulate the layout for the list view and detail (web view?), etc. Then give it an `ObjectProperty<Node> placeholder` to display if there is nothing in the list. Then you can set that any way you want, e.g. in FXML `<placeholder><fx:include source="..."/></placeholder>` to define it in FXML, or `<placeholder><Label text="..."/></placeholder>` or whatever. But "better"? In what sense? The question seems to be off-topic.

Comment: @James_D: the placeholder approach is not enough, as I need to replace more than just the list. I still don't know, based in what you said, how to have one FXML encapsulate two entirely different UIs.

Comment: I meant implement your own placeholder property, not use the one in the list view.

Comment: @James_D: that would mean creating a class that inherits from one of the containers and then managing to get the SceneBuilder to load it as a control, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stack pane. In the stack pane, add two containers (e.g. VBox) for each of the contexts above. Remember to create them with IDs

```
<StackPane fx:id="content">
 <VBox fx:id="context_1">
  <!-- the main view -->
 </Vbox>
 <VBox fx:id="context_2">
  <!-- view when there is no content -->
 </VBox>
</StackPane>
```

Now in your controller, have the three

```
@FXML private StackPane content;
@FXML private VBox context_1;
@FXML private VBox context_2;
```

Now have a method like

```
@FXML private void userHasAddedContent(){
 context_2.toFront();
}
```

Now inside the fxml, set onMouseClick to the button "Add new site" or you can put the above method in a method called by the button.

Comment: But the stack pane is see-through, isn't it? It's designed to apply effects.

Comment: Since I have other cases in which I need various panes like this (but they are dynamic), I started playing with this solution a bit more and adding this style: -fx-background-color: -fx-background;, to each element in a stack pane makes the opaque and behave as intended in my question.

Comment: I did use this method but I also used separate fxml files based on when I wanted to have separate controllers or re-usability of a component.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much on point.

If you want something entirely different to be displayed and not something with placeholder values as [James_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2189127/james-d) suggested, then you have to use a different `FXML` and a different `Scene` (no need to change `Stage` though).

Comment: The change happens inside in the UI, so, it's not just a matter of changing the scene in the stage.